# Facing issues in python Inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Trying to test inheritance with python. My scenario is like below..

**In a folder I’ve a base class named Asset_Base and a child class named Asset and they looks like below..**

in `Asset_Base.py` file:

```
class Asset_Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def sayHello(self):
        print('Hello!')
```

in `Asset.py` file:

```
import Asset_Base
class Asset(Asset_Base):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def sayHello(self):
        super().sayHello()

a = Asset()
a.sayHello()
```

while i run this Asset class **getting this error**..

```
class Asset(Asset_Base):
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

**After trying few things found it works fine if i just change the import statement like below**

`from Asset_Base import *`

**I’m new to python and not sure about the difference between**

`import Asset_Base` and `from Asset_Base import *`

**Can anyone please explain it a bit.**

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Check out [9.1 and 9.2](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) and [6.0 Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#modules) of the Python tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because in your first example, your class is inheriting from the `Asset_Base` *module* (that is, the .py file) -- *not* the class of the same name that it contains.

Note how your error message talks about `module.__init__()`.

Change your import statement so that it reads `from Asset_Base import Asset_Base`.

In addition, "module contains a class of the same name" is an anti-pattern in Python. Avoid doing that.

Comment: Also, note that avoiding the class having the same name as the module is easily accomplished by following the PEP-8 guidelines for names: `asset_base.py` would contain the class `AssetBase`, at the very least.

Answer (score 3):

```
import Asset_Base
```

imports a module (a file)

```
from Asset_Base import *
```

You import everything that is in your file (in this case the class Asset_Base)

For more information take a look into the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).